# Accidentally deleted master password in Firefox password manager

Tags: firefox, password-management

While trying to change the master password in Firefox, I accidentally removed it so that no password was needed to access my saved identifiers. I immediately realized it and put a new password.

Assuming that no one accessed the passwords in this short time and that no background backup software was running, should I still be concerned about the possibility that unencrypted passwords may still reside somewhere on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you said, if you have taken steps to ensure that the host OS is not compromised, it's highly unlikely that it was read, but there's always a chance that some of the unencrypted database was written to disk and may remain even after you set up a new master password & key. It depends on things outside of your control, such as the HDD or SSD's disk controller. You could mitigate that somewhat by using a utility to wipe free space on your drive.

In the longer term, if you consider your passwords to be this valuable, you might want to consider using a more sophisticated method for protecting them, such as [KeePass 2](http://keepass.info/). I use it myself to keep dozens of credentials at work and at home, and I believe everything is stored with AES256 or higher by default. You can then use [KeeFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/keefox/?src=search) to integrate into Firefox (the dev is working on porting it to the new WebExtensions framework too).